# Error training tensorflow model: can't find '__main__' module in 'Tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection-api

I am trying to train a tensorflow model on windows in jupyter notebook. Environment and object detection API installed correctly.

I run this command after configuring my paths:

```
print("""python {}/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir={}/{} --pipeline_config_path={}/{}/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=5000""".format(APIMODEL_PATH, MODEL_PATH,CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME,MODEL_PATH,CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME))
```

and get this output:

```
python Tensorflow / models / research / object_detection / model_main_tf2.py --model_dir = Tensorflow / workspace / models / my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path = Tensorflow / workspace / models / my_ssd_mobnet / pipeline.config --num_train_steps = 3000
```

however when I actually try to train the model in my terminal with the same output, it gives me the error:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't find '**main**' module in 'Tensorflow'

Can someone give some approaches on solving this error?

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to this path "tensorflow/models/research" and put this lines in command line:

```
cd /path-to/models-master/research/
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Then do this to avoid extra errors

```
cd /path-to/models-master/research/slim
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

regards.